# Reformating a large dataset in python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a large df from the WRDS CRSP database on monthly basis, which I need to reshape/reformat to be able to work with it.

the df looks like this:

| PERMNO | Date | Ticker | Prc |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 19851231 | ABC | -4.32 |
| 1000 | 19850101 | ABC | -2.12 |
| 1000 | 19851231 | DEF | -1.32 |
| 1000 | 19850101 | DEF | -6.72 |
| 1000 | 19850102 | DEF | +0.32 |

I need the unique Tickers as the header and unqiue dates(dateformat) as the index with the PRC matching ticker and date. I tried to convert tickers and dates to a list and create a new df with that, but I fail to match the Prc with ticker and date. It has to look like this:

| Date | ABC | DEF |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1985/12/31 | -4.32 | -1.32 |
| 1985/01/01 | -2.12 | -6.72 |
| 1985/01/02 | .... | +0.32 |
| 1985/01/03 | .... | .... |
| 1985/01/04 | .... | .... |

I tried to reshape it in a way I could use `pd.merge`, but nothing I tried did work.
Does anyone have any idea how to merge it properly or maybe an even better idea?

Comment: Can you show what you have tried? And, can you show what the output should be for the example data you provided? So far, I'm guessing you need to reformat/parse the dates so they can match, but I'm only guessing, because the question isn't clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need pandas `pivot`

```
df.pivot(index='Date',columns='Ticker',values='Prc')
```

Using sample data created as below

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
[19850101,'abc',1.0],[19850102,'abc',1.1],[19850101,'xyz',2.0],[19850102,'xyz',1.9]
],columns=['Date','Ticker','Prc'])
```

initial dataframe

```
       date ticker  prc
0  19850101    abc  1.0
1  19850102    abc  1.1
2  19850101    xyz  2.0
3  19850102    xyz  1.9
```

pivot output

```
    ticker    abc  xyz
    date
    19850101  1.0  2.0
    19850102  1.1  1.9
```

[Pandas Pivot Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html)

If you need to aggregate, say they are multiple prices for a certain date/ticket combination, you can aggregate

```
df.pivot_table(index='Date',columns='Ticker',values='Prc',aggfunc='max')
```

Comment: I tried that, but then I got the following error:  ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape.

Comment: @Djerun that means you have multiple date/ticker combination, like you have  
`[19850101,'abc',1.0],[19850101,'abc',4]` for example with 19850101 and abc having more than one price.  This case wasn't included in your question

Comment: Okay, it should not be like this, but I didn´t know. I look into this and get back.

Comment: @Djerun feel free to check it out or ask another question about the duplicates.  I added a little note about aggregating with pivots.  Often for something like price you can use max

Comment: thanks but I think I need to look at the definitons of the variables again. I tried your approach without any aggfunctions with the PERMNO variable and it worked perfectly fine. My Problem now is, that I thought the Tickers/date combinations should have been unqiue too at least I thought so. But thats my problem. Thanks a lot for your help. Really appreciate it.